# Angular app's variables won't display in html

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS while making a web application. I have gone through the tutorials and am starting with a simple list. I can't figure out why my browser only displays {{title}}

Here is part of my app.js module, where I defined the controller for this list:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
function TableauListCtrl ($scope, writeList) {

$scope.titles = [ // assigned test values 
    {item: 'wkbk1 title'},
    {item: 'wkbk2 title'},
    {item: 'wkbk3 title'}];

}
```

And here is the html where I try to access the array of titles:

```
<div id="List of Workbooks" ng-controller="TableauListCtrl" >
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="title in titles" ng-click="clickWorkbook(title)" ng-mouseover="mouseoverWorkbook(title)"> {{title}} </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So that only displays: {{title}} instead of the value in the array.

I used ng-app to specify the name of my angular module, and at the end of the html I used script tags to include the app.js file, among others. Can anyone catch my problem? Any help or insight would be appreciated, thanks!

[EDIT]

Okay that did fix itself when viewed in a fiddle. I am now trying to create a service that will make the list for me. Am I missing something in the syntax? Right now nothing shown in the rendered html. Here is the module, controller, and service definition, which are all currently in one file.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function TableauListCtrl($scope, writeList) {

    $scope.titles = writeList.readTitles();

}

app.service('writeList', function () {

this.addTitle = function (title, titles) {
    titles.push(title);
};
this.readTitles = function () {
    var titles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var title = "title " + i;
        addTitle(title, titles);
    }
    return titles;
};
});
```

Comment: A fiddle or plunker would help.  Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yvcTA/2/

Comment: Usually when I see the templates unmodified like that I have a javascript error somewhere that is preventing angular from starting up correctly.  I suppose in your case it might just be a configuration problem.

Comment: Hmm, okay! I'll keep tweaking the configuration. Thanks for the advice and the fiddle guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong variable.
`$scope.titles` is an array of objects

```
[ // assigned test values 
 {item: 'wkbk1 title'},
 {item: 'wkbk2 title'},
 {item: 'wkbk3 title'}]
```

So you should bind data with title.item and not with title.

```
<div id="List of Workbooks" ng-controller="TableauListCtrl" >
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="title in titles" ng-click="clickWorkbook(title)" ng-mouseover="mouseoverWorkbook(title)"> {{title.item}} </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```